Cannot run container structure test against OCI tarball in Bazel (rules_oci, container_structure_test)
I get the following error while running a container structure test against my tarball image using Bazel as the build system.
➜  monorepo-alpha git:(jalvarado/poc) bazel test //abacus/genesis:genesis_image_tarball_test
ERROR: /Users/josalvatorre/code/monorepo-alpha/abacus/genesis/BUILD.bazel:38:25: in container_structure_test rule //abacus/genesis:genesis_image_tarball_test:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_josalvatorre/5ad888b49df0a0d5e008e30fa7c56d14/external/container_structure_test~/bazel/container_structure_test.bzl", line 55, column 17, in _structure_test_impl
        fail("when the 'driver' attribute is not 'docker', then the image must be a .tar file")
Error in fail: when the 'driver' attribute is not 'docker', then the image must be a .tar file
ERROR: /Users/josalvatorre/code/monorepo-alpha/abacus/genesis/BUILD.bazel:38:25: Analysis of target '//abacus/genesis:genesis_image_tarball_test' failed
ERROR: Analysis of target '//abacus/genesis:genesis_image_tarball_test' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.064s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully
ERROR: No test targets were found, yet testing was requested

My build file looks like the following:
load("@container_structure_test//:defs.bzl", "container_structure_test")
load("@rules_oci//oci:defs.bzl", "oci_image")
load("@rules_oci//oci:defs.bzl", "oci_tarball")
load("@rules_pkg//pkg:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")

ubuntu_user_and_group = "ubuntu:ubuntu"

pkg_tar(
    name="source_code_tar",
    srcs=[
        "main.tf",
        "variables.tf",
        "outputs.tf",
    ],
    package_dir="/genesis",
)

oci_image(
    name="terraform_layer",
    base="@ubuntu_base",
    tars=["//terraform:terraform_tar"],
    user=ubuntu_user_and_group,
)

oci_image(
    name="source_code_layer",
    base=":terraform_layer",
    tars=[":source_code_tar"],
    user=ubuntu_user_and_group,
)

oci_tarball(
    name="genesis_image_tarball",
    image=":source_code_layer",
    repo_tags="genesis-repo-tags.txt",
)

container_structure_test(
    name="genesis_image_tarball_test",
    configs=["genesis-test.yaml"],
    image=":genesis_image_tarball",
    driver="tar",
)

I found the following examples on GitHub, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong:

e2e/smoke/BUILD.bazel
production/packaging/aws/data_server/BUILD.bazel

I'm pretty new to Bazel, so any debugging tips would be appreciated. I wish I would debug the rule itself.
Context
I want to build container images using Bazel. The recommended Bazel rules for this use case is Aspect's rules_oci. rules_oci mostly provides a way to build the images (which I can do successfully), but the project recommends using container_structure_test to test the image structure.

We recommend container_structure_test to run tests against an oci_image target (with driver="docker") or an oci_tarball target (with driver="tar").

I'm reluctant to test against the oci_image output because it's not the final artifact. As far as I understand, you always have to use oci_tarball to generate the final artifact, so testing against oci_image is inherently lower-fidelity.
Reproducing issue
My machine is an M2 Sonoma 14.5 Macintosh. However, I imagine the same problem would manifest on a Linux machine.
Check out my small PR (the first PR in my repo). I say "small" despite the 2,814 lines added because most of the lines come from the MODULE.bazel.lock file, which you can freely ignore.
Install Bazelisk using Homebrew and Docker Desktop. Make sure that Docker Desktop is open. Sorry if I'm forgetting some dependencies.
Go to the repository directory and run the following:
# This should succeed
bazel build //abacus/genesis:genesis_image_tarball
# This should fail
bazel build //abacus/genesis:genesis_image_tarball_test


I opened a GitHub issue with rules_oci. My issue was caused by an implementation change in 2.0, which they're about to release. 2.0 doesn't output a tarball like the previous major version.
They might or might not fix this. See the issue for updates. So far, the team favors the solution where container_structure_test adapts to support the implementation change in rules_oci.
Thankfully, running the container test against the image layer works fine, so I'll fall back to doing that.
